# ProGet performance issues

Tags: proget

My company is looking into hosting NuGet packages on a private server. We have started to play around with ProGet, however it seems to have performance issues. We are hosting around 6500 packages (120 unique ones + different version of them) and searching takes approximately 30s. It seems that it doesn't use the underlying database indexing at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

we were having this same issue around the same time, but it turns out it was just NuGet.org that was the problem. IT was really slow during those days... so I would suggest to disable your connectors. We have 100k+ packages, and use ProGet with no issues.